# Remover marcadores de um mapa no fim da animação

Tags: javascript, marcadores

Tenho um mapa com vários marcadores animados e gostaria que cada um deles fosse removido individualmente no fim do movimento respetivo. Estou a usar a biblioteca Leaflet, assim como Leaflet.MovingMarker. Já tentei usar os métodos `isEnded` e `end` sem qualquer sucesso.

Com este último, o seguinte código remove apenas um dos marcadores. Código completo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/o53njksy/219/)

```
marker.on('end', function() {
    map.removeLayer(this);
});
```

Um evento `click` no lugar de `end` funciona perfeitamente, todo e qualquer marcador é removível, mas não é isto que estou à procura:

```
marker.on('click', function() {
    map.removeLayer(this);
});
```

Também não tive nenhuma sorte com o método `isEnded`:

```
var ended = marker.isEnded(); 
if (ended = true) {
    console.log("this marker ended!");
    map.removeLayer(this);
}
```

Alguém entretanto sugeriu-me que o problema poderá estar relacionado com fechamentos dentro de laços (ver documento MDN sobre o assunto [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Criando_closures_dentro_de_loops.3A_Um_erro_comum)). Também estou convencido que é esse o problema, mas por muito que tente não consigo encontrar uma solução.

O que é que me está a escapar? Obrigado de antemão.